# Multiple categories linked to menu item

Tags: articles, menu-item, article-manager

Hi everyone i'm new here and also not really used to Joomla.

I got Joomla 3 and was wondering if i could link multiple categories to one menu item? Because i want to have on this side some articles, then a slideshow and afterwards some more articles form another category.

**To clarify:**
[image]

- *Blue*: Is already a category with articles
- *Green*: Is a slide show from a extension
- *Red*: Is where i would like to put some more articles in...

Does anybody know how this works?

Comment: you should add these categories into one parent category and link to that parent category.

Comment: you mean 2 categories in one upper category? Is it possible then to put a slideshow (plugin) between?

Comment: lets clarify it: you need a menuitem what is pointing to multiple categories?

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: the slideshow should probably be a module and loaded to the menu item with your nested categories

Comment: If any of the answers below have solved your issue, then consider to accept it as the right one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of trying to do nested categories you might want to just make a single article and link to that. Then use loadposition (or NoNumber modules anywhere) and just embed some modules INTO the page (not into module positions, though you could also do that).

Then you can stick whatever you want on the page, including a module that lists all the categories with links to them. You can literally custom build the entire article using modules. If your theme includes bootstrap you can even use grids and other goodies from bootstrap on it. The modules will just load into them where ever you want.

Comment: If you use this method - which I recommend - be sure to create a hidden menu item that links to the top level category so you can give them all the same settings (i.e. show intro text, show published date, etc) that they will inherit when clicked on.

Comment: @REactionFaye It’s a good solution but why do you recommend it ? I think it’s harder to  maintain a page where you call multiple modules. You can erase by mistake a part of the article when  you add content. That’s why i prefer multiple articles, each content is clearly separated.

Comment: Oh, no, I mean use the multiple articles - but then use modules to call in the specifics. So you start with an article that has a mod at the top calling your desired category. Then you use a mod to call your slider on the same page. Then you use a mod to call your next category of articles, and so on and so forth. You can style each as you desire, it's all on one page, and it's all dynamic.

Answer (score 5):

You can link to a category which has two child category (red and blue in your example).

Your Menu links to category A which contains category b (blue) and category C (red).

You can put your slider in an article which belong to category B or C.

Then, you can order your articles.

Comment: If you use this solution, remember you can also set category order - so you can ensure articles are being pulled from the right category for the top part. Then set your menu item to show 1 lead. That'll give you a leading class on the first article on the page that you can style up special.

Answer (score 1):

There can be more than one ways to achieve something like this, but many of them might require a bit of extra work and programming experience (custom menu items, template overrides or alternative layouts).

Brian's answer seems like the easiest and a straight-forward way for your case.
You can populate a single article that you will dedicate for this page, with all kinds of the modules you are going to need and adjust them to fit your requirements.

You can load a module with the [**loadposition**](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=joomla%20loadposition&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) **{loadposition myposition}**, by publishing the core loadposition plugin.

One of the most flexible modules that allows great flexibility when it comes to display articles from one or more categories, is the [RAXO all-mode](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/frontend-news/11399) module.

Although it is a paid download, I recommend this module for one more reason. It is a great piece of module software with clean code, which can help you learn a lot about Joomla modules and web development, if you decide to dig deeper and make changes to its code.